# Facebook Like dynamic content

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, single-page-application

So I have Single Page Application and everything is created trough ajax, even direct links create content dynamically.

I searched the web and found that I can share custom articles like this:

```
FB.ui({
  method: "feed",
  display: "iframe",
  link: "http://example.com/",
  caption: "Example.com",
  description: "Here is the text I want to share.",
  picture: "http://example.com/image.png"
});
```

But nothing for `Like` functionality.

I did some reading and found that `Like` buttons do need a SEO friendly url, which I actually can provide like this `www.example.com/?render_url='#/some/custom/hastag/url'`

But now I don't understand how can I provide `metadata` for that particular `Like`. At first I thought that `FB.XFBML.Parse()` is the solution, but that only renders the functionality nothing more.

So my question is: **Is it possible to implement `Like` functionality for completely dynamic website like SAP? I yes where can I see some example and/or read about method of doing it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this JavaScript View Framework

[**ReactJS**](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html)

and then I read this article [Using ReactJs with ASP.NET](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/04/04/reactnet.html)
where it's possible to seamlessly implement server side rendering in-par with the Framework itself.

So this solved my problem and now I can put `Like` buttons in my SPA Solution.